# trying to display:none or display:inline depending on the width of the screen with javasrcript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Should this not work, I'm a real beginner when it comes to javascript so I don't know why this isn't working. The reason I'm using javascript instead of css media queries is because the images are being toggled on and off with javascript and the css doesn't seem to over ride the js once it's called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.innerWidth > 1440) {
        ('#art1').style.display = 'inline';
        ('#art1_lores').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        ('#art1').style.display = 'none';
        ('#art1_lores').style.display = 'inline';
    }
```

This is where I am:
http://www.dillonbrannick.com/redesign

So the icons on the right affect the image on the left, before anything is clicked the css media queries work, but once you click one of the **first two** icons they don't, so I figured a javascript solution is probably the way to go but unfortunately my attempt is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your code into `window.onresize` handler. For example like this:

```
var art1 = document.getElementById('art1'),
    art1Lores = document.getElementById('art1_lores');

window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 440) {
        art1.style.display = 'inline';
        art1Lores.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        art1.style.display = 'none';
        art1Lores.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

window.onresize();
```

Also make sure you cache DOM queries, reselecting nodes again and again decreases performance.

http://jsfiddle.net/9J3cg/

Comment: Could I add in another clause that says if both 'art1' and 'art1_lores' are display:none to not apply the window.onresize clause?

Comment: Not sure I understand, like this? `if (art1.style.display == 'none' && art1.style.display == 'none') return; if (window.innerWidth > 440) { ...`.

Comment: I did `window.onresize = function() { if (art1.style.display === 'inline' || art1Lores.style.display ==='inline') { **your code above** } else { art1.style.display = 'none'; art1Lores.style.display = 'none'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use, jquery ? Did you linked to your jquery file?
If not, you should write:

```
  document.getElementById('art1').style.display = 'none';
```

or maybe try

```
   document.getElementById("art1").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('art1');

if (window.innerWidth > 1440) {
    element.style.display = 'inline';
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    element.style.display = 'none';
    element.style.display = 'inline';
}
```